# Eric Fernandez-Baca Audio show-reel

Tags: showreel

Hi guys, this is my first post although I joined this society last year, I was very busy finishing my studies. This is my first show-reel. I would appreciate any suggestions. Cheers!!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rx-WhgHBi0g

Answer (score 1):

im sure someone more suitable to give proper feedback will answer soon..

but i think you could get a bit more animated with it, especially with Ratatoullie. what i mean is hes a little rat in a (for him) massive kitchen, so you have license to go nuts with the sound, like when he pours that liquid, into the soup, to him that could be a massive splash, this could make it a bit more exciting.

im not very experienced and i don't even have a showreel myself, maybe someone else will chime in some better advice.

Answer (score 1):

Good effort, my advice would be to try not to think of the sounds too literally.  There's a magical element in this kind of stuff just as much in the sound design as the animation and I think that's what's lacking at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, it feels like a random smattering of sound effects floating over music with nothing to tie it all together.

In the Ratatoullie section, there needs to be more kitchen sounds -- it's not an empty kitchen, but by the sound of it there's no one in there cooking at all and the restaurant is completely empty.  Kitchens have LOTS of fan noise, too, for all the vents to take the smoke and steam out of the room.  Fridges hum, that pot should be audibly boiling, the hiss from the gas should be present the entire time (just mixed down).

In the Homenaje, I would do something to accent the callousness of the scissors snipping the fingernails, and when he bites off the rest of it the click sounds like what HE would hear, not what WE would hear.  Again, it needs more atmos.  The gunshot should be louder, because gun shots are CRAAAAZY loud in real life (also, a dryfire mixed in does wonders for realism).  Also, the Foley seems TOO loud, especially the cloth movement.

As for the demo, the woosh sounds for the text leaving the scene gets in the way of the design of the scene itself.  I would do separate reels for music and sound -- this reel feels more like a music demo than anything.

Finally, the "view the whole scene" text in the Ratatoullie and music video sections bugs the crap out of me; if I was watching your reel to select you as my sound designer, I wouldn't want to stop in the middle to go watch another video, and I wouldn't want to scroll back to the beginning to find the link. I'd just take that out completely.

All in all, though, good job.  You're farther ahead than I am -- I still haven't finished my damn reel -- but I feel like you should have been posting the individual clips over the last year to ask for critiquing.  I'd probably feel like less of a jerk, that way. :p

Oh, and welcome to SSD!

Comment: Man, I feel like a jerk.  I didn't mean to shut this thread down.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments! I also belive that some more atmosphere for the kitchen could be added, the thing is that it has to be considered also what you want to viewer to concentrate in and make decisions on what sounds you are going to dismiss to do sow, a good example of this type of compromise can be found in the cafe scene in the Film Inception. I'm curiously a Trained Chef and worked in Kitchens for many years. I agree there are many sound in the kitchen that are not present in the clip. I tied to keep it clear, specially hums and fans are not always the most desired sounds 

Comment: - Most desired sounds. As for the gun shot, you think you are also right it should be louder, if I wanted to be Hollywood style, unfortunately I think Hollywood is sometimes forgetting about our health. In the original film I have the shot around 12dB louder but I though the majority of the people who will listen to the reel will use headphones and I didn't want to deteriorate anyone's hearing!! Thanks again for your comments, I really appreciate them! 

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use copyright material in your showreel - assuming that you don't have permission to use Ratatoullie. Congratulations on finishing your studies.

Comment: It's a huge gray area -- what I've always seen, and recommend to do, is give credit where credit is due.

Comment: It's not a grey area when it comes to film, you cannot use video material without express permission of the creator in any kind of public forum. Creative commons material is the exception. Definitely always give credit where credit is due.

Comment: I really didn't think any one would assume I wanted to pass the Ratatouille animation as mine. I know that that is not really the problem on the other hand what I'm trying to show case in this clip is the audio, not the visuals. I did not find ant copy right restrictions about public forums though. I will have to read better the act. Thank you for your observations!